# Freelance App Development and Testing

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, beta-testing

I've contracted with a client to develop an iOS app and I'm almost done with the proof of concept level of the app. So far in my freelancing career I've programmed for clients that are also developers so I was able to transfer the app to them via GitHub. If I do contract with a client that doesn't have Xcode what is the best way to allow them to test the app, with TestFlight?

Also, for the above scenario concerning the final app would it be best to release it to the app store as a free app, or with a promo code or is there another preferred method that doesn't involve releasing an app that they wanted for personal use to the app store?

I've done a few google searches to see if I could find the best way but I don't think I'm asking the question right (i.e. not enough google fu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestFlight is great to showcase your app, will give your client 90 days to try it.

If your app is for personal use, I’m afraid Apple won’t approve it for the AppStore (happened to me :( ). According to Apple you should buy an `Apple Developer Enterprise Program` so you can distribute by yourself. You will need a distribution server too (your own “AppStore”) (I think it’s called an MDM)

[Read here](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/)

Good luck